# selection issue p:dataTable with selectionmode set to multiple nested in p:dataGrid

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, datagrid

I'm working on a PrimeFaces project, where I choose to use a p:DataTable inside a p:DataGrid. The DataTable has the selectionMode attribute set to "multiple". I have a button on the page and when I click on it, I want to get all the selected checkboxes inside the various generated tables. All the checkboxes bring the same type of information (they are in different tables because of an information grouping scheme I use in the project).

Since I have multiple DataTables in the final rendered page, how can I get the selected checkboxes? I tried using the `selection="#{myBean.selectedOptions}"` attribute of the DataTable, but it seems to get just one of the generated tables' selected options (aparently the first one). What can I do to get the selected options of all tables generated by the p:DataGrid? Javascript? Is there any point I'm missing in the DataTable behavior?

(Well.. I don`t know whether I was able to make myself clear enough - English is not my native language).

**[edited]**
More information:

- The number o DataTables generated is variable
- I tried using the jsf visit method to traverse the user interface component view [as shown here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/visit/package-summary.html), looking for all checkboxes inside the DataGrid, but it couldn't find any of the checkboxes (I printed out to the console all the elements found). I think it's because the checkboxes are encapsulated in DataTable component. This made me think about not using the selectionMode="multiple" and, instead, manually add the checkboxes and a hidden input element for each one so I can find the checkboxes (or the "input hidden") using the visit method. The sad part of this aproach is that I'd have to stop using some good stuff of the DataTable selectionMode="multiple" feature, like hilighting the row if the corresponding checkbox is checked, and the ready to use "check all" checkbox it automatically put in the header of the ckeckboxes column.
- I tried using a nested List in the selection attribute, but it didn't work. The main idea was using something like selection="#{bean.myListOfLists.get(t.counter)}". The "counter" variable is taken from the very object that is used to fulfill the current row of the DataTable (represented by the t variable in the attribute var="t"). The DataTable seems to not accept this approach. It doesn`t fulfill the nested lists.
- I tried using the above approch with a modification: instead of a list of lists, a build a new class "B" and made a list of B (selection="#{bean.myListOf_B_Objects.get(t.counter).listInsideBObject}"). The result is simliar to the last approach: none of the lists inside the B objects were fulfilled.

Below there is a simplified view of what I did (more similar to the last case, but it's just to get the big picture)

```html
<p:dataGrid var="gridCellContent"
            value="#{myBean.dataGridContent}"
            layout="grid" id="id01" columns="3"">

  <p:dataTable var="something" 
    value="#{gridCellContent.listOfSomething}"
    rowKey="#{something.id}"
    selection="#{myBean.listOf_B_Objects.get(gridCellContent.counter).listInside_B_Object}">
                                                 
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />

    <p:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{something.sometext}" />
    </p:column>

  </p:dataTable>


  <f:facet name="footer">
    <p:commandButton id="btnSave" value="Save" 
      actionListener="#{myBean.btnSave}"/>
  </f:facet>

</p:dataGrid>
```

**[edited 2]** Following @JaqenH'ghar's sugestion I tried out the modifications below, which unfortunately still din't work:

```html
<p:dataGrid var="gridCellContent"
            value="#{myBean.dataGridContent}"
            layout="grid" id="id01" columns="3"
            rowIndexVar="count">

  <p:dataTable var="something" 
    value="#{gridCellContent.listOfSomething}"
    rowKey="#{something.id}"
    selection="#{myBean.listOfLists.get(count)}">
                                                 
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />

    <p:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{something.sometext}" />
    </p:column>

  </p:dataTable>


  <f:facet name="footer">
    <p:commandButton id="btnSave" value="Save" 
      actionListener="#{myBean.btnSave}"/>
  </f:facet>

</p:dataGrid>
```

And for myBean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class MyBean {
  ...
  private List<List<Something>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<Something>>();

  public List<List<Something>> getListOfLists(){
    this.listOfLists.add(new ArrayList<Something>());
    return this.listOfLists;
  }

  public void setListOfLists(List<Something> listOfSomething) {
    this.listOfLists.add(listOfSomething);
  }  

  ... 
}
```

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of datatables? How many?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar, unforunately, the number of tables is variable. I think I`d be able to use jsf visit method if I had manualy added the checkboxes. But as I used a feature of the data table, the checkboxes, at the server side, is encapsulated inside the column object and cannot be visited as shown in [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/visit/package-summary.html] - I tried it.

Comment: You have the attribute rowIndexVar on both dataGrid and dataTable (try to print them out in the tables), which I thought could be used to index into a List<List<Something>>. But I can't get it to work... but thought that maybe you'd want to experiment with that. Afaik one should index with something like selection="#{bean.selectedSomething[rowIndexVar]}". Tried with both nested lists and nested arrays. So, sorry can't help but I'm interested in an answer too :-)

Comment: The problem is not how to index de list (but thanks anyway for the valuable information about the very useful rowIndexVar). I tried it in my code and it causes the same error of the version using t.counter. I think the problem resides in the getter (and, of course, in my newbie-experience with Primefaces). If you have other sugestions, I'll be glad to try them out in my code. I'll edit the problem above including the bean code I tried out.